# How to generate data from this particular multivariate distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling, multivariate-analysis, conditional-probability

Let $(X_0,X_1)$ be a random vector distributed according to the CDF $F_{(X_0,X_1)}(x,y)= \min (F_{X_0}(x),F_{X_1}(y))$ where $F_{X_0}(x),F_{X_1}(x)$ are the CDFs of $X_0,X_1$ respectively. We do not necessarily have densities.

I know how to sample from a one-dimensional CDF using inverse transform sampling. I want to sample from $F_{(X_0,X_1)}$

If $F_{(X_0,X_1)}$ had a density, then I could see how this might go:

- Generate $x_0$ from $F_{X_0}$
- Compute conditional density of $X_1$ given $X_0=x_0$,
- and generate $x_1$ from this density

But, here $F_{(X_0,X_1)}$ does not have a density.

What to do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If
$$\mathbb P(X_0\le x,X_1\le y)=\min \{F_{X_0}(x),F_{X_1}(y)\}$$
then
$$\mathbb P(F_0(X_0)\le F_0(x),F_1(X_1)\le F_1(y))=\min \{F_{X_0}(x),F_{X_1}(y)\}$$
Denoting
$$U_0=F_0(X_0),\quad U_1=F_1(X_1)$$
this implies that
$$\mathbb P(U_0\le u_0,U_1\le u_1) = \min(\mathbb P(U_0\le u_0,u_0<U_1\le u_1) =u_0,u_1)$$
and therefore that, when $u_1\ge u_0$,
$$\mathbb P(U_0\le u_0,U_1\le u_1) = u_0$$
meaning that
$$\mathbb P(U_0\le u_0,U_1\le u_1) - \mathbb P(U_0\le u_0,U_1\le u_0) = \mathbb P(U_0\le u_0,u_0<U_1\le u_1) =0$$
Similarly, when $u_0>u_1$
$$\mathbb P(u_1<U_0\le u_0,U_1\le u_1) =0$$
So $U_1$ cannot take values larger than $U_0$ and conversely, which implies that$$U_0=U_1$$with probability one.

**Conclusion:** To draw from this distribution,

1. generate a Uniform variate $U_0$
2. transform $U_0$ into $X_0=F_0^{-1}(U_0)$
3. transform $U_0$ into $X_1=F_1^{-1}(U_0)$

Comment: You omitted the last step: return the larger of $X_0$ and $X_1.$

Comment: @whuber: I do not think so as one need return a *pair* of random variables. Assuming all inverse are well-defined, $F_0(F_0^{-1}(U_0))=U_0=F_1(F_1^{-1}(U_0))$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out: I had misinterpreted the question by not noticing it concerned a bivariate CDF rather than a univariate one.  +1.

Comment: @whuber: However, the explanation you provided for the cdf remains valid within this question.

Comment: Clearly our analyses are closely related, but I don't want to confuse people with a post that doesn't directly answer the question and I haven't time to fix it up.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you Professor, does that mean that the conditional law of a marginal given another is a Dirac ? It seems like once we have $X_0$, we immediately get $X_1$, i.e $(X_0,X_1)=(X_0, F_1^{-1}(F_0(X_0)))$ in law ?

Comment: Yes, the joint distribution is supported by the curve $x_1=F_1^{-1}(F_0(x_0))$.